How to be safe from unwanted meanings?
I am going to register a name. It is a unique name, a play on the original English word. I will be receiving international audience, therefore, I want to make sure it does not have any undesired meaning in any language, or sound like a slang. How can I achieve this? How should I use tools like google translate to make sure about this?
Thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about linguistics.

There are 7000 languages and no-one knows them all. What you're asking isn't possible.

Unfortunately, even big companies with entire marketing departments can't always accomplish this. Ask speakers of a few of the most popular languages, if you want to make sure, but there's no way to be absolutely sure.

There are tools to translate a word using Google Translate in all of its supported languages. That may show if a word has problematic meanings in some languages, although of course it's far from a perfect solution.
